# vscode debugging can't hit breakpoints 'Program path uses differently cased character as file on disk'

Tags: node.js, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a node application in VSCode on OSX. I get the warning 'Program path uses differently cased character as file on disk; this might result in breakpoints not being hit' and sure enough I can't hit any breakpoints I place in the code.

I'm using the 'launch' configuration to run the debugger and my config looks like...

I've looked at this bug report but even using the application path rather than ${workspaceRoot} produces the same problem.

[VSCode issue 2613](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2613)

I run the same code and debug no problem on Windows.
My build is

OSX El Capitan

Node 6.1.3

VSCode 1.4

Any help is again appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about OSX, but in windows i had a similar issue and resolved it by changing the case of the folder name. The actual foldername was Src instead for lower case src.
`"program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/main.js"` to
`"program": "${workspaceRoot}/Src/main.js"`.

Comment: I even had a case where the ${workspaceRoot} part wasn't matching because I had recently done a fresh Git clone and the new folder name was  myproject but in VSCode the project was called MyProject.

Answer (score 2):

The part of `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",` in your launch.json is case-sensitive and must match your actual js file. So the following launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/NoDeSeRvEr.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

Needs a `NoDeSeRvEr.js` file

Answer (score 2):

This is really an annoying problem. I tried a few ways to walk around but finally found the solution.

You just need to close the cached recently open project and open the project again by clicking File -> Open...

Then the warning "Program path uses differently cased character..." will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the app.js file you have created, may be you have mistype the name of file or have used uppercase (App.js) for 'app.js'. I hope it will help to correct the bug.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had "à" in the file path, replacing it with an "a" solved for me!

Answer (score 0):

As Kurt Van den Branden has already said the program part is important. In my case l noticed l was working under 2 subdirectories so the path wasn't being picked up even though l typed out the correct file.(Copy Relative path is available when you right click the given file, it is one of the drop down options)

Solution: Copy relative path of the file you want to debugg and paste it like so:
`"program": "${workspaceFolder}/CopiedRelativePath"`.